# Date with date_format is sorted on alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

I am trying to SELECT the date from my database in the `date_format` '%e %M %Y':

```
SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date FROM table
```

The output of the date will be like: `1 january 2016`.

When I add an ORDER BY to the query I the date will not sort on the date, but it sorts on alphabetical order.

Does someone know how I can fix this problem and sort column: `date` on the date order?

Here is my full statement:

```
SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS date FROM table ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: try using a different alias for the formatted date

Comment: do not `date` as a column name or alias at all (it's a SQL keyword) .... and it leads to this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `date` as alias for column name. Just use another one:

```
SELECT date_format(date, '%e %M %Y') AS formatted_date 
FROM table 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```